# User flow for providing multiple versions (environments) of mobile app to end users

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We are trying to provide multiple environments to our end users and want to create one single bundle for both IOS and Android. Currently we have a hidden feature (clicking on the version number to open an environment selection screen: Dev, QA, UAT or Prod). However, I am wondering if there are better or recommended ways of achieving this same effect somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with Android on managing Environments using Gradle file.

Let's say you have a app with package name - `com.company.sampleapp`

In gradle your `applicationId` will be `com.company.sampleapp`

Now we can create different flavors for different environment and we can also have different `applicationId` as shown below.

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
       production {
           dimension "default"
           applicationId 'com.allegion.leopard'
       }
       //App will have package name appended with .qa
       qa {
           dimension "default"
           applicationId 'com.allegion.leopard.qa'
       }
       //App will have package name appended with .dev
       dev {
           dimension "default"
           applicationId 'com.allegion.leopard.dev'
       }
   }
}
```

Once this is done, you can choose build variants and create APK for that build. Added image for clarity

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.